# C++ Same Equation but different results with (Calculator vs C++)

Tags: c#, c++, c++11, numbers, equation

*I have been working on a short project the last two days, but now everything falls apart,* **because there is one equation which returns 8.660254 when calculated in a C++/C# program but 0 when you try to calculate it by hand or with a calculator.**

*Equation:*

```
float mgr1 = (x + tr * 0.5f - tr / 2) * 1.73205f * 10.0f;
```

*In my case:*

```
x = 0;
tr = 1;
float mgr1 = (0 + 1 * 0.5f - 1 / 2) * 1.73205f * 10.0f;
```

The right result is `0` but when calculated in C++, like this, it returns `8.660254`? Am I getting crazy? Is there something about C++ which I do not know? What is it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Integer division on 1/2 gives you 0. Change that to 1.0/2 and you will get the result you expected ... *approximately* correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The / operator for integers returns a integer, not a floating-point value. 1/2 is 0.

1.0/2 or 1/2.0 return what you expect.